# Elasticsearch query subfield directly without prefix

Tags: elasticsearch

If have a object like this in elastic search, where `a` is a object with some fields (dynamically mapped)

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": "b_value",
    "c": "c_value"
  },
}
```

How can use query 'b:b_value' to get matched documents without have to specify 'a.b:b_value'?

I tried searching online but none of them work, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [field alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/field-alias.html).

An alias mapping defines an alternate name for a field in the index. The alias can be used in place of the target field in search requests, and selected other APIs like field capabilities.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-field-aliases-in-elasticsearch